# Spring boot tomcat not responding when curl from another ip address in the same subnet

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat9

When i start spring-boot with tomcat9 in a windows machine, i can access in this way from the same machine:

curl 192.168.1.13:3000

i can also :

curl localhost:3000

however when i do:

curl 192.168.1.13:3000 from another machine in the same subnet, spring-boot tomcat does not respond

i have tried running express.js on the same machine on port 3000 and when i curl 192.168.1.13:3000
i get a http response, so i think its not a firewall issue with the port number (since port number is 3000 for both express.js and spring-boot tomcat)

how can i setup spring-boot tomcat9 so that it will respond to a request coming from another ip address that is not localhost?

I have server.address=0.0.0.0 in application.properties

Comment: Have you configured the `server.address` property? By default, Tomcat should bind to 0.0.0.0 and, therefore, listen on all available addresses.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson server.address is set to 0.0.0.0 on application.properties file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

previously i ran the spring boot application with mvn spring-boot:run
and it did not respond to curl from another computer from the same network

then i tried 
mvn package
java -jar target/demo.jar

then the server responded to curl from another computer from the same network